# Sucesión de Fibonacci en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

En mi código me muestra un error, lo he tratado de solucionar de varias formas, controlando en el iter varias variables pero tampoco. Adjunto el código y un ejemplo de prueba

Si value = 5
            Muestra:
0
1
1
2
3

```
class Resolution:
    """Clase que resuelve la secuencia de Fibonacci"""

    def __init__(self, value):
        if type(value) == int and value > 0:
            self.__valor = value
        else:
            raise ValueError

    #-------------------El código de arriba no se puede modificar-------------------

    def __iter__(self):
        self.valor = 0
        self.end = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.valor < self.fin:
            self.inicio, self.saltos = self.saltos, self.inicio + self.saltos
            self.valor += 1
            return self.inicio
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas siempre mantener almacenados los dos últimos items de la secuencia generados para calcular el siguiente. Además de esto, necesitas otra variable que actúe de contador y que permita la terminación del iterador cuando se alcance `self.__value`. En tu caso esta variable sería `self.value`. Teniendo esto en cuenta, tienes varios errores:

- Si suponemos que `self.end` en `__iter__` es el último item calculado, este atributo es el mismo que `self.saltos` en `__next__`, usa el msimo nombre en ambos métodos.
- Te falta definir un atributo para almacenar el antepenúltimo en `__iter__`, que vendría a ser `self.saltos` en el `__next__`.
- La comparación inicial, la que controla el final del iterador, debe ser `if self.valor < self.__valor` en todo caso. El iterador termina cuando el número de fibonacci generado es mayor que el numero introducido en el `__init__` (`self.__valor`).
- Tal como planteas el algoritmo, debes retornar el número almacenado en la variable que almacena el antepenúltimo item calculado antes de reasignarle el nuevo valor.

Modificando los nombres de las variables para intentar no confundir, el código podría quedar como:

```
class Resolution:
    """Clase que resuelve la secuencia de Fibonacci"""

    def __init__(self, value):
        if type(value) == int and value > 0:
            self.__valor = value
        else:
            raise ValueError

    #-------------------El código de arriba no se puede modificar-------------------

    def __iter__(self):
        self.actual = 0
        self.siguiente = 1
        self.cont = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        fib_num = self.actual
        if self.cont < self.__valor:
            self.actual, self.siguiente = self.siguiente, self.actual + self.siguiente
            self.cont += 1
            return fib_num
        else:
            raise StopIteration

print(list(Resolution(5)))
```

Comment: Gracias, pero el código está parcialmente correcto, puesto que, si la paso unos test unitarios me falla en tres de ellos. Para los que me fallan son para los siguientes casos: valor = 2.

Se hacen más iteraciones de las esperadas

valor = 10

Se hacen menos iteraciones de las esperadas

valor > 10

Se hacen menos iteraciones de las esperadas

Comment: He editado la respuesta, inicialmente había entendido que el generador tenia que generar items hasta que el valor del item llegue al argumento pasado al inicializador. Ahora genera n items de la secuencia, que creo que es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, gracias por su tiempo y ayuda. He podido entender el ejercicio y la secuencia